# how to identify which UITextField editing did end inside of the IBAction?

Tags: swift, xcode, ibaction

I have assigned single IBAction(Editing Did End) to multiple UITextField, how to identify which UITextField editing did end inside of the IBAction?

Comment: Add [tags](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622493-tag)

Comment: Tags has worked for me thanx.

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

- Use an editing did end IBAction with a sender parameter, and interrogate the sender (which will be the text field who's editing has ended)
- Set yourself up as the `UITextFieldDelegate` for each text field. If you set yourself up as the `UITextFieldDelegate` and implement the `textFieldDidEndEditing(_:reason:)` method, the first parameter of that method is the text field who's editing has ended.

I've actually never used an IBAction for the `editingDidEnd` or `editingDidEndOnExit` events. I always use the `textFieldDidEndEditing(_:reason:)` method in the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol.